# Reflection Issues with Optaplanner

Tags: java, maven, reflection, optaplanner

I'm building an optimization program using `Optaplanner 6.2.0.CR4`, and I'm running into reflection issues with the `ReflectionPropertyAcessor class, line 63: return readMethod.invoke(bean)` and the other invoke methods in this class. Debugging the code, I'm usually able to "Step-into" the code into whatever of my classes it's calling, but Eclipse throws an error every time it reaches the end of whatever method is being called. This results in `Method.invoke(Object, Object) line not available`, `DelegatingMethodAccesorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line not available`, `GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Object, Object[]) line not available` and then a screen asking me to change the attached source.

I'm running `JRE 1.8`, and I have the source code for Optaplanner imported into Eclipse as its own Maven project, with my code as its own separate Java project for now. I'm pretty new to using Maven and build tools in general. Could this error be a result of bad dependencies, classpath, etc? Is there a better way to set up my project? I'm in the process of moving my code into a Maven project also.

Answer (score 0):

What stacktrace are you getting in a normal run?

The call `readMethod.invoke(bean)` can fail if bean isn't an instance of the class for which the readMethod applies. If that's the case, I'd be interested in seeing the code, because optaplanner might be able to detect that fail-fast with a helpful error message.

Debugging won't work because `Method.invoke` is probably a native implementation (C instead of Java) in the JDK.

Comment: Interesting, and I'm not getting a throw declaration on a normal run. Everything compiles and the planning entity returns null for each move attempt.

Comment: "planning entity returns null for each move attempt" => I can't understand that sentence :)

Comment: Sorry, here is a line from the output while my code is running:

`10:44:25.980 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (0), time spent (145), score (0hard/0soft), selected move count (100), picked move (2014-04-11_B@` **null** `=> pilot no:0).`

Comment: To help you understand, my code is using shift assignments as a planning entity, where the date_letter is a shiftDate_shiftType. The null value following the @ is supposed to be a pilot

Comment: A ChangeMove's toString() is entity.toString() + " => " + toValue.toString(). The examples's entity.toString() always mentions the original value too. So that picked move is moving that shift from pilot null to pilot no:0. Because it happens during the CH which initializes all entities, this seems perfectly normal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand. I'm curious then why debug is being thrown. Up to this point I've been assuming it's an error on my part and I've been stepping through the code looking for places where the code breaks down. Another question: is it ok if the same move count number is used multiple times? (Move count 100 is used for all the moves shown in my output)

Comment: yes. Move count is the number of moves evaluated in a step. Turn on trace logging to better understand what's going on by seeing the actual moves.

Comment: In any case, I don't understand what you're trying to fix, what the problem is.